# Xamarin.ios using DLL library

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I have `xamarin` binding project (represents kind of bridge to native `iOS` static library) which works fine if added to a solution.

What I'm trying to do is to use /bin/libary.dll instead of binding project.

I created new `xamarin.ios` simple view project, added reference to library.dll.

Project compiles fine using API from that library but when run i'm getting fatal error:

[image]
so there is no even entry point to application

sorry probably for posting obvioues answer, but I need to get it working fast.

Comment: You're trying to load a Windows DLL in OS X?

Comment: You mean this DLL is actually kind of microsoft dll (shared library) and I can't use it on os x?

Comment: _Dynamic-link library (or DLL) is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept in the Microsoft Windows and OS/2 operating systems_  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)

Comment: the thing is why it is generated under OS X, BUT I can't use it? And does it mean if I just use this source on windows it just would work?

Comment: If you are trying to reference the dll produced by the binding project instead of linking directly to the binding project itself, then yes it should work.

Comment: but it doesn't as long as I reference to this dll in my project, without - it  works

Comment: if it's not then I suspect there is something wrong with your binding setup.